# Struggling wtih ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

In R, `pwfun = function(x) {`

`ifelse(x < -1,-2*x-2,0)`

`ifelse(x > 1,x^2-1,0)`

`}`

with `pwfun(c(-2, 0.5, 3))`
Gives me `[1] 0 0 8`
Which is clearly wrong, where it should output `2 0 8`.

How can I correct the code to output correct numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using two independent `ifelse` condition, the second one takes advantage on the first one. You can use nest two ifelse condition to make it work correctly:

```r
pwfun = function(x) {
  ifelse(x < -1, -2*x-2, 
         ifelse(x > 1, x^2-1, 0))
}
pwfun(c(-2, 0.5, 3))
# [1] 2 0 8
```

or using, `if` and `else` (only works for single values, so should use apply the function to all the values in the vector, e.g. using `sapply`):

```r
pwfun = function(x) {
  if(x < -1){
    -2*x-2
  }else if(x > 1){
    x^2-1
  }else 0
}

sapply(c(-2, 0.5, 3), pwfun)
# [1] 2 0 8
```

Comment: I'd be explicit that the `if` / `else` version only works on single values, which is why you needed `sapply`.